# c++ if statement malfunction

Tags: c++, if-statement

why are my else if loops not working
the code when ran skips over the else statement and executes the if statement even if it is not true

```
   #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int a;
    int b;
    char operation;
    int sum;
    int sub;
    int mul;
    int divide;
    int mod;
    int main()
    {
    cout<< "enter a number \n";
    cin >> a>>operation>>b;
    if (operation= '')
    {
        sum=a+b;
        cout << a<<operation<<b<<sum;
    }
    else if (operation= '-')
    {
        sub=a-b;
        cout << a<<operation<<b<<sub;
    }
    else if (operation= '/')
    { if(b==0){
        cout<<"You cannot divide by zero";
    }
        else{divide=a/b;
        cout << a<<operation<<b<<divide;}
    }else if (operation= '*')
    {
        mul=a+b;
        cout << a<<operation<<b<<mul;
    }
    else if (operation= '%')
    {
        mod=a%b;
        cout << a<<operation<<b<<mod;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Invalid input";
    }

        return 0;
    }
```

the output is always just adding the numbers no matter what sign the input has it wont go over my else if statements even if the operation isnt + infact even if i use a wrong operation it just adds the two numbers

Comment: Typos galore. Instead of `if (operation= ' ')`, use `if (operation == ' ')`. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: Sadly `=` != `==`

Comment: Also keep an eye on `if (operation = '')`. Looks like you're missing the character.

Comment: Use your compiler warning: `gcc -Wall foo.c`

Comment: Note: Many modern compilers will issue a warning for assignment in a conditional since it's a common typo. If your compiler doesn't see what warning options are provided. In GCC and similar I use `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. `-Werror` is a good idea when learning because it forces you to deal with the warnings. In Visual Studio, [set the warning level to 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2017) Warnings are the first line of defense against logic errors. They are your friends. Do not ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two thing to get right,

the comparison in the if statement should be done with `==` not with `=`

`=` will assign the rightside value to the variable operation also you missed `+` in the first comparison

`if (operation= '')` should be `if (operation == '+')`

Comment: It is best to not answer questions that are typos. They make it harder for the automated clean up scripts to remove. Now that it's been upvoted a human's going to have to get involved.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks!